# Compare dict items with each other get matching ones for timeframes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is what i have to do, we have a lot of different businesses.
Each opens and closes on different days some from monday to friday.
Some from tuesday to friday and some have monday - friday from 8-12 and from 14-18.

For example:

```html
 hours = {
'monday_c': '18:00',
'saturday_c': None,
'monday2_c': None,
'thursday2': None, 
'thursday': '09:00',
'friday_c': '18:00',
'monday2': None,
'saturday2': None,
'friday': '09:00', 
'tuesday': '09:00',
'thursday2_c': None, 
'wednesday_c': '18:00',
'tuesday2_c': None,
'friday2': None,
'tuesday_c': '18:00', 
'wednesday': '09:00',
'sunday_c': None,
'sunday2': None,
'thursday_c': '18:00',
'sunday': None,
'monday': '09:00',
'saturday': None, 
'friday2_c': None,
'wednesday2_c': None,
'wednesday2': None,
'tuesday2': None, 
'saturday2_c': None, 
'sunday2_c': None
}
```

As you can see in the dict monday is the opening time and monday_c is the closing time. if for example mon2 has a value it means there are two opening times. Like in the example above.

I need to compare these hours and find a way to detect every possible combination and print them out.
Mo-Tu and We-Sa or Mo-Fr and Mo2-Fr2 or Mo-Th or Tu-Sa and so on.

What is the smartest way to do that ?
i was trying to loop through each of them and compare them to each of the values.
However covering each of them without duplicating has proven a bit challenging for me.
If statements for each possibility seems crude.

I wrote a simple code that would work in this case: `

```html
 if hours['monday'] == hours['tuesday'] and hours['monday_c'] == hours['tuesday_c'] \
    and hours['monday'] == hours['wednesday'] and hours['monday_c'] == hours['wednesday_c']\
   and hours['monday'] == hours['thursday'] and hours['monday_c'] == hours['thursday_c'] \
   and hours['monday'] == hours['friday'] and hours['monday_c'] == hours['friday_c']:
  print('open mon-fri from 09:00 - 19:00')
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do but this doesn't feel like the right data structure

Comment: @e4c5 thank you for the reply i'm trying to display for example it is open from monday - friday from 9:00 - 18:00. Instead of Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr from 09:00-18:00. The Dicts are predefined.

Comment: I am still confused here. since you write in your original post Tu-Sa, etc? Does the starting day matter or are all combinations possible as long as there are no dupes? can it be sa-mon? or tuesday-mon?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy this is one of several dicts, it could be possible that one has open from tuesday-saturday from 9:00 - 12:00 and from 14:00-18:00. All combinations could be possible the starting day would be nice if it would be the first day. tuesday to monday would mean mo-so that would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have completely misunderstood you then this is what you are looking for. You'll need a 3rd party package simply to save space on a bunch of `if` statements. Do `pip install fuzzywuzzy[speedup]` before running this.

```
import itertools
from fuzzywuzzy import process

combos = list(itertools.combinations(hours.keys(), 2))
valid_choices = []

for tup in combos:
    if process.fuzz.ratio(tup[0], tup[1]) > 80 or tup[0].endswith('c'):
        pass
    elif tup[0] != tup[1]:
        valid_choices.append(tup)

print valid_choices

('tuesday', 'friday2')
('tuesday', 'wednesday2')
('tuesday', 'thursday_c')
('tuesday', 'saturday')
('tuesday', 'wednesday2_c')
....
```

For the sake of brevity I didn't print all the choices. I also excluded all choices where the first portion of the tuple starts with a closing date since I did not know if that is a valid choice or not. If it is a valid choice just remove `or tup[0].endswith('c')` from the first `if` statement in the `for` loop.

Comment: It appears i really suck at explaining, the one hours dict that is above should only give back one result which is mo-fr from 09:00 - 18:00. If you have another dict where monday = 11:00 and monday_c = 15:00 and tuesday = 11:00 and tuesday_c = 15:00 and the rest stays the same. it should display mo-di = 11:00 - 15:00 & mi-fr = 09:00-18:00.

Comment: I just looked at google maps results and facebook business pages. It appears no one is capable of displaying opening times like that.

Comment: still making no sense, your first comment makes no sense, what is `di`?

Comment: sorry my fault, i typed in german. DI is tuesday. If you look at foursquare and search for any business and look at the opening hours. It will always display the days of the week it is opened without printing each day separately. That is the format i would like to have.

Comment: i wrote some code pretty quickly that would give the correct result for this dict. But would not work in other instances. For example if there are 2 opening times or if the start day is not monday.

Comment: the code makes no sense, do you mean `hours.get('monday')` since `hours` is a dict.

Comment: yes i'm a bit preoccupied and tried to answer as fast as possible ;)

Comment: I adjusted the code, now this returns the correct result but only in this case.

Comment: so if theres two opening times you want both those combos returned? and if there is two closing times, same scenario? and the starting day could not be monday if monday has no value associated with it?

Comment: correct if the starting day has no value associated with it should jump to tuesday if this also has no value jump to wednesday and so on. if there are two opening times there has to be two closing times. For example it is open from monday to tuesday 09:00(monday,tuesday) - 12:00(monday_c, tuesday_c) and 15:00(monday2,tuesday2) - 17:00(monday2_c,tuesday2_c) and from thursday to sunday from 09:00 - 13:00 and from 15:00 - 17:00. I have pretty much given up if i'm honest there are to many scenarios. Restaurants have a lot of different business hours.